# Django Python: Get the uploaded file name and add it to the body of the email message

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django for a simple contact form with a file upload.

I'm not attaching the file to the email; I'm simply uploading it to the server via forms.py. But I need to add the file name in the body of the contact form email so I know which file has been uploaded by which email user.

How do I get the uploaded file name and add it to the body of the email?

Does `file = fs.save(request_file.name, request_file)` output the file name?

If not, how do I get the uploaded file name? And add it to the email?

I am also aware that Django adds a random string of characters to the uploaded file name if it sees an existing file with the same name n the upload directory, so in that case, I need that file name included.

**views.py**

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

from contactform.forms import ContactForm
from contact.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, EMAIL_HOST

def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'thanks.html', {})

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

        request_file = request.FILES['document'] if 'document' in request.FILES else None
        if request_file:
             fs = FileSystemStorage()
             file = fs.save(request_file.name, request_file)
             fileurl = fs.url(file)

        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['To'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['Subject'] = f'Site Email'
            message = f'Name: {form_data["name"]}\n' \
                      f'Email address: {form_data["email_address"]}\n\n' \
                      f'{form_data["message"]}' // How do I insert the file name in the message body?
            msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

            with smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT) as server:
                server.ehlo()
                server.starttls()
                server.login(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
                server.sendmail(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_USER, msg.as_string())

            return redirect('contactform:thanks')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'contact.html', { "form": form })
```

Comment: It looks like you already have the file name as `request_file.name`. What more do you need? Just add this to `message` however you want.

Comment: Also, you should look at the django email integration. It allows you to generate the body of the email from a django template.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I can't get the file name added to the body of the email.

Comment: What did you try? Do you know about f-strings? If not, then I suggest you read about them.

Comment: I've been trying enes islam's answers using f-strings with no luck

Comment: As you say, there's a syntax error. Part of the reason for that is they do too much in a single line. Also, it does extra work that you've already done by assigning a variable `request_file`. Just use `request_file.name`.

Comment: Ok, like `msg['Message'] = f' File: {request_file.name}'` ?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: That doesn't work. Since I'm using `f'{form_data["message"]}` do I need to append `request_file.name` to that `message`?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out: `f' File: {file}\n\n' \`

Answer (score 2):

No need to use another `msg` field; this works. All that is needed is `file`, since `file = fs.save(request_file.name, request_file)` gets the filename.

This also adds the correct file name in the message if Django has added random characters to prevent same name file overwrites:

```
message = f'Name: {form_data["name"]}\n' \
                      f'Email address: {form_data["email_address"]}\n\n' \
                      f'File Uploaded: {file}\n\n' \
                      f'{form_data["message"]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.FILES.get('file_name').name` like this:

```
msg['Message'] = f'Hi, You uploaded {request.FILES.get('filename').name}. Thanks!'
```

*Don't forget to add .get before file name*

Comment: Still doesn't work; invalid syntax error on that line.

Comment: try print(request.FILES.get('filename').name)

Comment: you need to change the 'filename' by yours

Comment: I think the issue with this answer is the `'filename'` inside the f-string which also uses single quotes. You can fix this by assigning the file name to a variable which you then use in the f-string.